# AngularJS $locationProvider.search() results in Uncaught Object error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS I get an error when attempting to use the $locationProvider to parse the query string.  The AngularJS Docs say that locationProvider hasn't moved from the core, so I'm wondering why the code below doesn't work.  It sets html5Mode fine, but it's like the search method doesn't exist.

```
var myApp = angular
    .module('agencyMatrix', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    var location = $locationProvider.search();
}
```

Comment: Is .search() expecting parameters?, It also might just be $location.search();

Comment: I tried just $location.search(), same error, and the search() method returns an object of the parsed query string when given no parameters, per the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`search()` is actually defined on `$location`, not `$locationProvider`.

See the [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location#search) documentation and the source: [angular.js/src/ng/location.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/498835a1c4d0dc6397df4dd667796b09565fedf4/src/ng/location.js#L398-L465)

To use `$location.search` you can access it inside run instead of config:

```js
var myApp = angular
    .module('agencyMatrix', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}]).run(['$location', function($location) {
    var location = $location.search();
}])
```

The [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) guide from the angular documentation (specifically, the [Provider Recipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe) section) describes the configuration phase and how it is different from the other phases (for example, `$location` itself is unavailable during the configuration phase).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that being the case, is there a way to configure a route based on the querystring?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to do with the query string?

Comment: The long and short of it is that I am trying to pass the query string from a url to the view, which is actually a php file.  If I enter the URL site.com/#/reports/financial?action=view I'd like my templateUrl function to be able to return reportFinancial.php?action=view to the view.

Comment: @Peter Turns out you don't have to use `$location` at all to do that.  Here's [an example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BbuPRk9WLqB5aLQXXciR?p=preview).  If you pass a function to `templateUrl` the first argument of the function are the route's parsed query parameters.  See [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for more information.

Comment: I know I can do that, and that is the eventual goal via a restful API, but currently, I'm trying to shoehorn angular into an existing application and I want to preserve as much functionality as possible and if I could trap the querystring while still inside the router, I could do that.  I've been reading the docs for the last two hours and it doesn't look like this is actually possible.